# Calculating Interest Rate From EMI

Tags: loans, interest-rate

Suppose there is a loan with equated monthly installments. If I know the loan period, loan amount and equated monthly installment amount,  is there a way to calculate the interest rate?

EMI= a * (1 + r)^p / [(1 + r)^p - 1]

a: loan amount

r: interest rate

p: loan period

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to solve for the interest rate.  Also your formula should be

```
EMI = a*r*(1 + r)^p/((1 + r)^p - 1)
```

Derived from the sum of the discounted payments being equal to the principal

[image]

[image]

[image]

Example solution

```
a = 1000
p = 3
r = 0.05

∴ EMI = 367.209
```

Suppose the interest rate is unknown

```
EMI = 367.209
a = 1000
p = 3
```

solve for varying `r` until this equation is satisfied:

[image]

*Plot of* `(EMI (1 - (1 + r)^-p))/r - a` *over a range of* `r`

[image]

or use an online solver, e.g.

[image]