# Effective compounded interest rate with multiple interest rates

Tags: interest-rate

I'm looking for the effective annual compounded interest rate of an investment which requires me to save a fixed monthly amount, but the interest rate decreases as the investment gets closer to maturity. For example:

The investment starts out in a high growth phase of 10% for 24 months, which is followed by a medium growth of 8% for 12 months and the finally a low growth phase of 4% for 12 months. With each month requiring the same fixed payment.

I've been trying like crazy to find a formula, but most annuity type formulas work on changing payments over time rather than changing interest rates.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is the formula for an annuity with initial amount

[image]

where

```
a is the initial amount
d is the periodic deposit
r is the periodic interest rate
d is the periodic deposit
n is the number of periods
```

Chaining together three calculations

```
a1 = 0
r1 = (1 + 0.1)^(1/12) - 1
n1 = 24

a2 = (d (1 + r1) ((1 + r1)^n1 - 1))/r1 + a1 (1 + r1)^n1 = 26.5451 d

r2 = (1 + 0.08)^(1/12) - 1
n2 = 12

a3 = (d (1 + r2) ((1 + r2)^n2 - 1))/r2 + a2 (1 + r2)^n2 = 41.1826 d

r3 = (1 + 0.04)^(1/12) - 1
n3 = 12

FV = (d (1 + r3) ((1 + r3)^n3 - 1))/r3 + a3 (1 + r3)^n3 = 55.0884 d

∴ d = 0.0181527 FV
```

or without values, the general case for three rates is

```
FV = ((-d r1 (1 + r2) + (1 + r2)^n2 (d (r1 - r2) +
      (1 + r1)^n1 (d + (a1 + d) r1) r2)) (1 + r3)^n3)/
      (r1 r2) + (d (1 + r3) (-1 + (1 + r3)^n3))/r3

∴ d = (r1 r2 r3 (FV - a1 (1 + r1)^n1 (1 + r2)^n2 (1 + r3)^n3))/
       (-r1 r2 (1 + r3) + (1 + r3)^n3 (r1 (r2 - r3) +
       (1 + r2)^n2 (r1 - r2 + (1 + r1)^(1 + n1) r2) r3))
```

And if the initial amount `a1` is zero

```
d = (r1 r2 r3 FV)/
     (-r1 r2 (1 + r3) + (1 + r3)^n3 (r1 (r2 - r3) +
     (1 + r2)^n2 (r1 - r2 + (1 + r1)^(1 + n1) r2) r3))
```

***Obtaining the equivalent fixed rate***

Solving for `r` where

```
FV = (d (1 + r) ((1 + r)^n - 1))/r
d  = 0.0181527 FV
n  = 48

r = 0.00551856

Effective annual rate = (1 + r)^12 - 1 = 6.82701 %
```

Comment: Thanks Chris! And is there a formula to essentially average out the interest rates over the lifetime of the investment? If my understanding is correct, would this be the geometric mean?

Comment: Hi, I take it you mean reversing the calculation to find out what the average rate would be over the 4 years.  With known `FV`, `d` and `n` the formula `FV = (d (1 + r) ((1 + r)^n - 1))/r` can't be solved algebraically for `r`, but you can solve it numerically by graph or solver, e.g.  https://money.stackexchange.com/a/120192/11768

Comment: Yes that is what I meant. Ok great, thanks for the help!

Comment: Using a solver, with `d = 0.0181527 FV` and `n = 48`, `r = 0.00551856` ∴ effective annual rate is `(1 + r)^12 - 1 = 6.82701 %`.

Comment: It's not the geometric mean (`7.97187 %`) because, for example, the lower 4% rate takes effect on a larger amount of the savings, in the last year.

Comment: Hi Chris, would you be able to send me the formula to calculate "FV" and "d" if there are 5 interest rates? I've been starting at the formula that you sent above but can't seem to work it out. My math is not what it used to be :)

Comment: Sure `FV = ((((a1 (1 + r1)^n1 + (d (1 + r1) (-1 + (1 + r1)^n1))/r1) (1 + r2)^n2 + (d (1 + r2) (-1 + (1 + r2)^n2))/r2) (1 + r3)^n3 + (d (1 + r3) (-1 + (1 + r3)^n3))/r3) (1 + r4)^n4 + (d (1 + r4) (-1 + (1 + r4)^n4))/r4) (1 + r5)^n5 + (d (1 + r5) (-1 + (1 + r5)^n5))/r5`

Comment: `d = -((-FV + a1 (1 + r1)^n1 (1 + r2)^n2 (1 + r3)^n3 (1 + r4)^n4 (1 + r5)^n5)/(((1 + r1) (-1 + (1 + r1)^n1) (1 + r2)^n2 (1 + r3)^n3 (1 + r4)^n4 (1 + r5)^n5)/
     r1 + ((1 + r2) (-1 + (1 + r2)^n2) (1 + r3)^n3 (1 + r4)^n4 (1 + r5)^n5)/
     r2 + ((1 + r3) (-1 + (1 + r3)^n3) (1 + r4)^n4 (1 + r5)^n5)/
     r3 + ((1 + r4) (-1 + (1 + r4)^n4) (1 + r5)^n5)/
     r4 + ((1 + r5) (-1 + (1 + r5)^n5))/r5))`

Comment: [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) makes computational algebra a piece of cake.